# My program won't put the grade

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this assignment we are supposed to make a class in Python where we put 3 scores and have to find the average and the grade the student has. It works but I'm having an error. When I put in a whole number (e.g 73) three times it will show the letter grade. But when I enter a number with a decimal (e.g 83.7) three times it doesn't show the letter grade and that is the kind of number we need. Is there a way I can make it show the grades when I input numbers with a decimal? And why does it only work for the whole numbers?

```
class grades:
    def __init__(self,name,test1,test2,test3,avg):
            self.name = name
            self.test1 = test1
            self.test2 = test2
            self.test3 = test3
            self.avg = avg

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getTest1(self):
        return self.test1

    def getTest2(self):
        return self.test2

    def getTest3(self):
        return self.test3

    def getAvg(self):
        return self.avg


#main:
name = input("Enter the students name: ")
test1 = float(input("Enter the first score: "))
test2 = float(input("Enter the second score: "))
test3 = float(input("Enter the third score: "))
avg = float(test1 + test2 + test3) /3.0
grades1 = grades(name,test1,test2,test3,avg)
grades1.name
grades1.test1
grades1.test2
grades1.test3
grades1.avg
print("The student's name is:" ,grades1.name)
print(grades1.name +"'s test scores are:")
print("---------------------------:")
print("TEST1: \t\t\t",grades1.test1)
print("TEST2: \t\t\t",grades1.test2)
print("TEST3: \t\t\t",grades1.test3)
print(grades1.name +"'s average is: \t",grades1.avg)
##if avg <= 100.0 and avg >= 90.0:
##    print(name +"'s grade is: \t A")
##elif avg <= 89.0 and avg >= 80.0:
##    print(name +"'s grade is: \t B")
##elif avg <= 79.0 and avg >= 70.0:
##    print(name +"'s grade is: \t C")
##elif avg <= 69.0 and avg >= 60.0:
##    print(name +"'s grade is: \t D")
##elif avg <= 59.0 and avg >= 0.0:
##    print(name +"'s grade is: \t E")
if avg >= 90.0 and avg <= 100.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t A")
elif avg >= 80.0 and avg <= 89.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t B")
elif avg >= 70.0 and avg <= 79.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t C")
elif avg >= 60.0 and avg <= 69.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t D")
elif avg >= 0.0 and avg <= 59.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t E")
```

The reason why I have the first grade part commented is because I tried both the ways with no luck.

This is what I tried but no luck with the decimals

```
Enter the students name: k
Enter the first score: 89.9
Enter the second score: 89.9
Enter the third score: 89.9
The student's name is: k
k's test scores are:
---------------------------:
TEST1:           89.9
TEST2:           89.9
TEST3:           89.9
k's average is:      89.90000000000002
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I entered `75.3` `76.3` and `77.3` and I got a `C` average.   show your example input please.

Comment: Do you get an error or are the `if-elif` statements skipped? (Which seems impossible)

Comment: What if an average is between, for example, 89.0 and 90.0?

Comment: @RyanHaining This is what I did and it didn't work              Enter the students name: k
Enter the first score: 89.9
Enter the second score: 89.9
Enter the third score: 89.9
The student's name is: k
k's test scores are:
---------------------------:
TEST1:     89.9
TEST2:     89.9
TEST3:     89.9
k's average is:   89.90000000000002

Comment: This script works for me. I entered in three decimal values and it gave me a letter grade. Can you show more information about the error?  -- NWard

Comment: You gave us the wrong values. See @chepner 's comment!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `if`s.  You have no case for when the average is between `89` and `90`, `79` and `80` and so on.  Additionally you don't need any of the `and`s outside of the first one, because each previous check will have confirmed what the `and`s are again checking for.  You can shorten most of your `if`s to a single condition.

```
if avg > 100 or avg < 0:
    #check for out of range grades first
    print('Grade out of range')
elif avg >= 90.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t A")
# if the elif is reached, we already know that the grade is below 90, because
# it would have been handled by the previous if, if it were >=90
elif avg >= 80.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t B")
elif avg >= 70.0:  # other wise the previous check will have caught it
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t C")
elif avg >= 60.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t D")
elif avg >= 0.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t E")  # should this be 'F' instead of 'E'?
```

and just cause I'm a nice guy ;)

```
class Grades:
    def __init__(self, name, *tests):
            self.name = name
            self.tests = list(tests)

    @property
    def avg(self):
        return sum(self.tests)/len(self.tests)

    @property
    def letter_avg(self):
        avg = self.avg
        if avg > 100 or avg < 0:
            raise ValueError('Grade out of range')
        elif avg >= 90.0:
            return 'A'
        elif avg >= 80.0:
            return 'B'
        elif avg >= 70.0:
            return 'B'
        elif avg >= 60.0:
            return 'D'
        elif avg >= 0.0:
            return 'F'

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.tests)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """Allows access such as 'grades.test1' """
        if attr.startswith('test'):
            try:
                num = int(attr[4:])-1
                return self.tests[num]
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                raise AttributeError('Invalid test number')
        else:
            raise AttributeError(
                'Grades object has no attribute {0}'.format(attr))


def main():
    name = input("Enter the students name: ")
    test1 = float(input("Enter the first score: "))
    test2 = float(input("Enter the second score: "))
    test3 = float(input("Enter the third score: "))
    grades1 = Grades(name, test1, test2, test3)
    print("The student's name is:" , grades1.name)
    print(grades1.name +"'s test scores are:")
    print("---------------------------:")

    for index, test in enumerate(grades1):
        print('TEST{0}: \t\t\t{1}'.format(index, test))

    print("{0}'s average is {1}".format(grades1.name, grades1.avg))
    print("{0}'s average is \t {1}".format(grades1.name, grades1.letter_avg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if-elif` statements do not cover all possible values. For example, if the average is 89.5, none of the blocks will catch it. The easiest way to fix this is to just remove the `<=` clauses from your `if-elif` statements, since they are unnecessary.

```
if avg >= 90.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t A")
elif avg >= 80.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t B")
elif avg >= 70.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t C")
elif avg >= 60.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t D")
else:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t E")
```

Comment: But wouldn't the <= >= be necessary because it is basically saying it is less than/greater than or equal too the number.

Comment: No, because if the first `if` fails, then it will `have` to be less than 90.0 already, so that condition in the first `elif` statement is unnecessary. The same goes for each successive `elif` statement (you already eliminated the `<=` case in the previous `elif`. (See the edit to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some boundary cases, for e.g`89.9`, `79.7`, averages like these are not going to print any grade in your program.

You need something like this:

```
if avg >= 90.0 and avg <= 100.0:
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t A")
elif avg >= 80.0 and avg < 90.0:       #should be <90 not 89.0
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t B")
elif avg >= 70.0 and avg < 80.0:       #should be <80 not 79.0
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t C")
elif avg >= 60.0 and avg < 70.0:       #should be <70 not 69.0
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t D")
elif avg >= 0.0 and avg < 60.0:        #should be <60 not 59.0
    print(name +"'s grade is: \t E")
```

**Demo:**

```
The student's name is: dfgd
dfgd's test scores are:
---------------------------:
TEST1:           89.9
TEST2:           89.9
TEST3:           89.9
dfgd's average is:   89.90000000000002
dfgd's grade is:     B
```

**Update:**

A cleaner solution here is going to be `bisect` module:

```
import bisect
lis = [0,60,70,80,90,100]
grades = list('EDCBA')
ind = bisect.bisect_right(lis,avg) -1 
print(name +"'s grade is: \t {}".format(grades[ind]))
```

Comment: So I should replace the numbers like 79,89 etc with 80,90? Cuz I just put what the rubric said to put

Comment: What about the value `80.0`, it satisfies two conditions, you should remove the `=`, for more clarity, I guess. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra `avg = 80.0` prints `B`, which I guess is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is, since it encounters the first `elif`, but I was just talking about clarity. :)